# How to do a simple insert into the local database file sqlite with javascript

Tags: node.js, insert, electron, sql.js

I try to insert data into a local database sqlite. Its possible. I can do it  . But I have to create a new table every time. I try to do it without creating a new table...

I already insert the data into the table but I had to create a table every time.

```
     $("#ecris").click( function() 
        {          

              var fs = require("fs");         
              var sql = require("./js/sql.js"); 
              var db = new sql.Database();                   
              db.run("CREATE TABLE test (col1, col2);");

              db.run("INSERT INTO test (col1, col2) VALUES ('8','4564')"); 
;  
              var data = db.export();

              var buffer = new Buffer(data);
              fs.writeFileSync("bd/mybd.sqlite", buffer );
              db.close();   



        });
```

**I just need the insert into the existing table... thanks a lot**

Comment: insert does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why creating & writing to same file everytime,

instead check if file already exists, then reopen your db file "bd/mybd.sqlite" and directly insert data to table, you can get syntax easily on net.

Update to read a database from the disk:

```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var SQL = require('sql.js');
   var filebuffer = fs.readFileSync('test.sqlite');

  // Load the db
  var db = new SQL.Database(filebuffer);
```

Ref: https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: its a good idea to get the syntax on the net thnaks a lot....realy usefull I don't ask a question when I have the solution...I dont know how to reopen the db file

Comment: I have just added code on how to reopen DB file, refer mentioned readme URL.

Answer (score 0):

finally find thanks for your help !

```
$("#ecris").click( function() 
{          

     var fs =  require('fs');         
     var sql = require("./js/sql.js");      
     var filebuffer = fs.readFileSync("bd/mybd.sqlite"); 
     var db = new sql.Database(filebuffer);
      db.run("INSERT INTO test (col1, col2) VALUES ('gerald','coucou')");
     var data = db.export();
     var buffer = new Buffer(data);
     fs.writeFileSync("bd/mybd.sqlite", buffer );
     db.close();

});
```